# Having trouble finding time-complexity of nested for loop

Tags: loops, nested, big-o, complexity-theory

So I've been trying to find big-Oh complexity using the following algorithm:

```
for (i = 1; i ≤ n;i + +)
     for (j = 0; j < n; j = j + i)
          print(Array[j]);
```

I was told that the optimal way would be represent using summations, and I know it can be represented in some form of a series, I really just don't know where to start. I can see that the outside loop iterates n times, but the inside loop is what gets me. I was hoping I could get a push in the right direction here rather than the answer.

Comment: The inner loop can be rewritten. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you expand the number of summations in both the for loops. The array indices should look as follows

> > (0,1,2,....n-1), (0,2,4,...n-1), (0,3,6,9....n-1) .....(0,n/2),(0)

If we observe the first parenthesis has **n**, the second has at the worst case **n/2** and so on till the last parenthesis has **1**.
So total number of summations can be written as

> > Summations = Sum(from i = 1 to n) [n/i]

Try solving the summation and you will get the total number of summations

Comment: You may wish to double-check that.  It seems that the loop bounds for j do not depend on the loop bounds for i.  So, this should just look like: (0,1, 2, ...n-1),(0,1,2, ... n-1) ... (0,1,2, ... n-1) repeated n times.

Comment: I think my summation is right since the innerloop is incremented as j = j+i. It would've been the case you are mentioning had it been j = j+1

Comment: I stand corrected.  I misread the i as a 1 in the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use summations as you suggested, for a more analytical/algebraic approach.

First, consider only:

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    //some O(1) operation
```

This is simple, because the var `i` takes all the range of integer values from 1 to n.
We can express this loop with the following summation:

[image: sum 1]

Now, consider only:

```
for (j = 0; j < n; j = j + k)
    //some O(1) operation
```

where k is a constant positive integer term (like 1, 2, 3, ... or etc.), and `k <= n`

In this case var `i` **doesn't** take all the range of integers values from 0 to n-1. For example,  let `k=2`, then we can represent what is going on in the following image:

[image: range k2]

What you see in black is the interval of possible integers, and what is in red represent the actual integer values var `i` takes. As you see, var `i` is "jumping" over odd numbers to reach n-1, so in this case (when `k=2`) only even numbers are taken.

As result, when `k=2`, the complexity is given by the summation:

[image: sum 2]

In general, a similar approach can be done for any k. In particular, note that as k tends to n, the complexity will tend to decrease.

For our purposes we can rewrite the loop:

```
for (j = 0; j < n; j = j + k)
```

As:

```
for (j = 0; j < n/k-1; j++)
```

Both have the same complexity.

Finally, consider:

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
     for (j = 0; j < n; j = j + i)
          //some O(1) operation
```

In the inner loop, we have `i` playing the same role our `k` before. This means that the inner loop is going to be executed with every possible value of `i` in the range 1 to n.

Rewrite as:

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
     for (j = 0; j < n/k-1; j++)
          //some O(1) operation
```

Therefore, the complexity is given by the following two nested summations:

[image]

First, start evaluating with the inner summation (the right one):

[image]

**NOTE** that i changed the var name from `i` to `x` accidentally, but that is not really important.

We have here exactly the same result given by the other poster.

Now if you just expand the last summation the result is:

[image]

Now what you have in brackets is the **n-th harmonic number**, not to confuse with harmonic series. This are interesting numbers in discrete mathematics (and other fields).

This can be denoted as:

[image]

Note that from this analysis you can obtain an asymptotic tight bound.

BTW: you can check the last equation in this [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum[Sum[1%2C%20%7Bj%2C%200%2C%20%28n%2Fi%29-1%7D]%2C%20%7Bi%2C%201%2C%20n%7D]%3DSum[n%2Fx%2C%20%7Bx%2C%201%2C%20n%7D]%3Dn*Sum[1%2Fx%2C%20%7Bx%2C%201%2C%20n%7D]%3Dn*%281%2B1%2F2%2B1%2F3%2B...%2B1%2Fn%29%3Dn*HarmonicNumber[n])

The syntax is:

```
Sum[Sum[1, {j, 0, (n/i)-1}], {i, 1, n}]=Sum[n/x, {x, 1, n}]=n*Sum[1/x, {x, 1, n}]=n*(1+1/2+1/3+...+1/n)=n*HarmonicNumber[n]
```

I hope this helps.